# What does a simple MODIFY with no parameters change in ALTER TABLE (SQL)?

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table

```
alter table emp  
modify mgr;
```

Are previous constraints dropped/retained?
What is the use of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#i2181663)

> **modify_col_properties**
>
> Use this clause to modify the properties of the column. Any of the optional parts of the column definition (datatype, default value, or constraint) that you omit from this clause remain unchanged.

So it's a no-op if you don't specify any properties. It is not, in itself, very useful.

Comment: It could be used (eg by framework code) to test the presence and *modifyability* of emp.mgr. (if it is not discarded a no-op before the catalogs are consulted) If it works that way, it is probably cheaper than select count(...) for that purpose.